# What is the meaning of "being on birth control"?

Tags: word-usage

I read about it all over the place and they say it is a way of preventing pregnancy using contraceptives like condoms, pills, etc. However, in a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/BLZM19D1hig?t=2m6s), I heard someone recommending condom use to a guy, saying "Even if your girlfriend is on birth control, I still recommend using a condom." Does this mean that colloquially, US people use birth control to specifically mean contraceptive pills?

Comment: Generally, in the US, "on birth control" implies that the female (since there is no common male "pill") is using the "pill" or one of the other regularly-scheduled drugs (eg, there are some injections, I believe) to prevent pregnancy.  This as opposed to an instance-based contraceptive such as a condom or diaphragm.

Comment: Saying that someone is _on `X`_ means that it is a drug (good or bad) that they take regularly. Since there is no male birth-control drug, this phrase is limited to women taking contraceptives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Being on birth control*** means that a girl is taking a contraceptive pill (or injection). Notice the preposition *on*, which means "regularly taking (a drug or medicine)" (sense 10, [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/on)).

*Being on birth control* is also known as ***being on the pill*** ([here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+pill)). Only a female can be *on* birth control in this sense.

***Using birth control*** refers, more generally, to *any* contraceptive practice, including condoms, diaphragms, pills, etc. ([here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/birth%20control)). *Both* males *and* females can use birth control, in this sense.

Thus, *birth control* is *not* used only to refer to female contraceptive pills.

Comment: Looks like the second paragraph [won't be correct for much longer](https://utswmed.org/medblog/pill-guys-male-birth-control-option-passes-safety-tests/). :)